# jQuery Tools Scrollable Navigatior Plugin not working with Firefox 7

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

When viewing [jQuery Tool's Scrollable Example](http://www.flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/one-sized.htm) with Firefox 7 on a Mac, the top navigation does not click / scroll.

I've tested it with Chrome, Safari and IE8 and it works well, just not Firefox.

I've narrowed it down to the following code:

```
.navigator({

    // select #flowtabs to be used as navigator
    navi: "#flowtabs",

    // select A tags inside the navigator to work as items (not direct children)
    naviItem: 'a',

    // assign "current" class name for the active A tag inside navigator
    activeClass: 'current',

    // make browser's back button work
    history: true

})
```

It looks like anything that has to do with the `navigator` plugin doesn't get fired.  I used Firebug and it has no feedback.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: Problem not solved with the new version 8.0 of Firefox. History has to remain set to 'false' in order for the plugin to work correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set history to false or just remove the history option and it should work! Hope you don't mind much about keeping history/back button working...

Answer (score 1):

This actually works and you can keep your history functionality.  I located this in the help forums:

Inside your jQuery tools JavaScript file find:

```
history.pushState( {i:0} )
history.pushState( {i:c} )
```

replace with:

```
history.pushState( {i:0}, '' )
history.pushState( {i:c}, '' )
```

Actual credit should go to the person who found the solution:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/55/83477